# Change style of tabs in bootstraps tab view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I require a vertical tab view in my site. I need to change the color, add glyphicon and a decorator line underneath the tab title. Is this possible with the tab view of bootstrap?

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked btn-group" style="width: 100px;">
   <li  class="active"><a href="#div_message">Home</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#div_message">Profile</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#div_message">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: jsfiddle or live demo plz..

Comment: Is this what you want? [link](http://codepen.io/joshadamous/pen/wJKzv/)

Comment: like this type ??? http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab

Comment: you can also set your own tabs Home, Profile and more with set of icons

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  /*Styles for your choice*/ 
  .nav{
    width: 300px; 
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
  }
  .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
  }

  .nav-pills > li > a {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .nav a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .nav a:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
  }
  li:hover .line{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 10px;
  }
</style>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 HEADER">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home
          <div class="line"></div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Profile<div class="line"></div></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Messages<div class="line"></div></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 CONTENT">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what you want!
Yes, you can modify the CSS style of Bootstrap. The nice way to manipulate then is using firebug and specting the element what you want to modify.
Getting in the right side the classes of the element and now you can copy this classes, paste in your css file and edit then.

Never edit the core css file of the bootstrap, it is a nice pratice. Ever rewrite the code in others files ^^

Now use the jquery to put nice dynamic styles to your menu and change the properties that i put.

[image]